# How to combine two update queries having different where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I combine this two update statements :

```
update Special_quota set Status=0,Additional_msg_quota=0 where User_id not  in('1','2','3') 

update Special_quota set Status=1,Additional_msg_quota=30 where User_id in('1','2','3')
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having two statements, but take a look at transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CASE expression like this:

```
UPDATE Special_quota 
set Status = CASE WHEN User_ID IN('1','2','3') then 1 else 0 end,
    additional_msg_quota = CASE WHEN User_ID IN('1','2','3') then 30 else 0 end
```

Comment: there is a problem with 't'

Comment: @Anirudh Why did you accept his answer ? he copied mine!

Comment: sorry i checked his first when he gave answer.and its working.i didn't know that he replicated.

Comment: @Anirudh He gave the same answer exactly 5 minutes after mine

Comment: answer me this question I have table called Contacts(Contact_id,Status) with some data. I have another table called Msgs(Contact_id,num). I want to 'Insert' all the Contact_id's of contacts where Status =1 to Msgs with number=10.

Comment: if u answer i will ask him. if he cant reply ,it means he is copy cat

Comment: hey @sagi, u gave an answer which never worked, man... Now you have nicely edited it and u r telling me I copied yours...

Comment: hey guys i got problem who ever solves it he is winner. i am getting an error for the solution "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.\r\nThe statement has been terminated." solve it pls

Comment: @Anirudh go fetch. Nickal have fun.

Comment: share knowledge to help others and don't crave for points....... and dont cry. i am changing the accept

Comment: one more thing even ur answer is not wrkng.there is an error.

Comment: You really think I need you or your points in any way? Thats the principal that matter, and yes , this is a site to share knowledge. And now I dont wanna share mine with you, so ask someone else.

Comment: if u don't want reputition why do u want accept to be changed

Comment: For the principal that nickal won't get them.

Comment: I really don't care any more, its became to long conversation, stop posting here. We'll close it like this: If you want help, ask from someone else.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Special_quota
set Status = CASE WHEN User_ID IN('1','2','3') then 1 else 0 end,
    Additional_msg_quota = CASE WHEN User_ID IN('1','2','3') then 30 else 0 end
```

Comment: You just copied my answer are you serious?

Comment: How can you even know that?

Comment: And thats not an excuse of copying an answer and removing an alias.