# Combine multiple update statements

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm wondering would that be possible to combine the following two queries or more?
The current behavior is going to do the two times of table scan to the tableB, I wish after the combination then would be one time scan to the tableB.
Thanks.

```
update tableA A
 set A.column2=B.column3
      from tableB B
        where A.column1 = B.column1
        B.column2=1111
        and B.column3 is not null;


update tableA A
 set A.column2=B.column4
      from tableB B
        where A.column1 = B.column1
        and B.column2=2222
        and B.column4 is not null;
```

Comment: You would use case statements to allow the query to set values on different conditions like you have here.  This is similar to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533828/how-to-combine-two-update-queries-having-different-where-condition.

Comment: As your queries read now there is no connection between tableA and tableB. Is that correct?

Comment: @Dresden  the thing is that the case statements don't allow me to do "select from where "

Comment: @nscheaffer You are right, table A and table B are in different DB so that I need to use "from where" to setup the connection.

Comment: those don't even look like valid "single" updates.

Comment: If you ran the statements in succession every row in table a would get updated to table b column 3 of the last record from table b that meets the criteria as you have no relationship between table a and b defined.  Is there a shared key?  A value range?.....

Comment: @Matt    Hi Matt, I edited the example so that the shared key between two tables is column4.

Comment: @Uueerdo Hi Uueerdo, sorry, I just added a new condition "A.column4 = B.column4" to fix the query.

Comment: Still doesn't look like a valid MySQL update to me; but perhaps as Matt's answer below indicates, this is a Microsoft SQL Server matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be sql-server syntax would be and I am pretty sure this crosses over but I have seen some articles that suggest other syntax for mysql.  But basically use a `join` or `where` clause that will `relate` the tables and then use a `case` statement to choose your value.  In the solution below you will never use the `ELSE` of the `case` statement but for good measure reference the current column value for anything that would match your `join` but not your `case` statement conditions.

Using a JOIN

```
UPDATE a
    SET Column1 = CASE
       WHEN b.Column1 = 1111 THEN b.Column2
       WHEN b.Column1 = 2222 THEN b.Column3
       ELSE a.Column1
    END
FROM
    [DatabaseA].TableA a
    INNER JOIN [DatabaseB].TableB b
    ON a.Column4 = b.Column4
    AND (
          (b.Column1 = 1111 AND b.Column2 IS NOT NULL)
          OR
          (b.Column1 = 2222 AND b.Column3 IS NOT NULL)
       )
```

Per your comment of not using a join.

```
UPDATE a
    SET Column1 = CASE
       WHEN b.Column1 = 1111 THEN (SELECT b.Column2 FROM TableB WHERE b.Column4 = a.Column4)
       WHEN b.Column1 = 2222 THEN (SELECT b.Column3 FROM TableB WHERE b.Column4 = a.Column4)
       ELSE a.Column1
    END
FROM
    TableA
WHERE
    EXISTS (
       SELECT *
       FROM
          TableB
       WHERE
          b.Colmn4 = a.Column4
          AND (
                (b.Column1 = 1111 AND b.Column2 IS NOT NULL)
                OR
                (b.Column1 = 2222 AND b.Column3 IS NOT NULL)
             )
```

That looks crazy but it will only update the rows you are intending to. Otherwise if you don't care if you update the entire column you could do something like this.

```
UPDATE a
    SET Column1 = CASE
       WHEN b.Column1 = 1111 THEN ISNULL((SELECT b.Column2 FROM TableB WHERE b.Column4 = a.Column4 AND b.Column1 = 1111),a.Column1)
       WHEN b.Column1 = 2222 THEN ISNULL((SELECT b.Column3 FROM TableB WHERE b.Column4 = a.Column4 AND b.Column1 = 2222),a.Column1)
       ELSE a.Column1
    END
FROM
    TableA
```

You can also do it with a single subselect if you are willing to update the entire table.

```
UPDATE a
    SET Column1 = ISNULL(

       (       SELECT (CASE WHEN b.Column1 = 1111 THEN b.Column2 ELSE b.Column3 END)
       FROM
          TableB
       WHERE
          b.Colmn4 = a.Column4
          AND (
                (b.Column1 = 1111 AND b.Column2 IS NOT NULL)
                OR
                (b.Column1 = 2222 AND b.Column3 IS NOT NULL)
             )
        ),a.Column1)    
FROM
    TableA
```

The trick in all of these answers is you have to be able to relate the SELECT statement of TableB with TableA otherwise you will not get your intended result.

Comment: In MySQL, you would remove the `FROM` and move join statement to first line as: `UPDATE [TableA] a INNER JOIN...`.

Comment: Hi Matt and Parfait, thanks for your help! This approach will work in mysql/sql.

Comment: I get rid of join statement so that another approach is like following:        UPDATE a
    SET Column1 = CASE
       WHEN b.Column1 = 1111 THEN b.Column2
       WHEN b.Column1 = 2222 THEN b.Column3
       ELSE a.Column1
    END
FROM
    [DatabaseB].TableB b
    WHERE a.Column4 = b.Column4
    AND (
          (b.Column1 = 1111 AND b.Column2 IS NOT NULL)
          OR
          (b.Column1 = 2222 AND b.Column3 IS NOT NULL)
       )